# How to encrypt passwords stored in a file rather than /etc/shadow in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, password-encryption

I want to create a new file called `/home/secret.txt` with the usernames and passwords stored, similar to `/etc/shadow` format in Linux. All new users are placed into this new file rather than `/etc/shadow`. From my bash script I am doing as follows:

```
echo "user1:password::root:root:/home/user1:/bin/bash" >> /home/secret.txt
echo "user1:password" | chpasswd -c MD5
```

In the 2nd statement, I am trying to change the password into encrypted but `chpasswd` fails saying `chpasswd: line 1: user 'user1' does not exist`. I think `chpasswd` changes/encrypts passwords for the users present in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow. Because of this the password field in the file is not encrypted.

May I know how to write username and password similar to `/etc/shadow` format into a temporary file with passwords being encrypted ?

Comment: Have you tried with the `--stdout` option to check the output?

Answer (score 3):

You are right `chpasswd` changes/encrypts passwords for the users present in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`. Hence If you mean to say "all new users are placed into this new file rather than `/etc/shadow`", you mean to say that, change in the Code itself of `useradd cmd`.

As of now, I don't see, it is possible to write username and password similar to `/etc/shadow` format into a temporary file with passwords being encrypted, without having an entry in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something similar to the following:

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz "user1:password"
```

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow) answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with to store usernames and passwords into a different file than shadow.

1. Initially from my init script I am creating multiple users as below:

   ```
   echo "user1:password1::root:root:/home/user1:/bin/bash" >> /home/secret.txt
   echo "user2:password2::root:root:/home/user1:/bin/bash" >> /home/secret.txt
   echo "user1:password1" | chpasswd -c MD5
   echo "user2:password2" | chpasswd -c MD5
   if [ /* Condition success */ ] ; then
        /* Copy the required users to new file */
        grep -wE "(user1|user2)" /etc/shadow >> /home/secret.txt
        /* Deleting users from shadow */
        sed -i '/user1/d' /etc/shadow
        sed -i '/user2/d' /etc/shadow
   fi
   ```
2. For the new users introduced to the system using `adduser` will go through a custom wrapper which checks for a condition based on which the users are placed into new file or shadow file. Similarly deletion and authentication also holds the similar process in-order to remove and authenticate these users into the system.